# Finding the exact shell variable with grep/awk/sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to find an **exact** match of a certain string that contains backslashes and spaces, but I can't seem to get the correct technique that only returns one match (see example). The problem occurs where there are more 'versions' of the same variable, as shown below.

Two examples of variables would be:
*variable_i_want="Database\Base\location of site"

variable_dont_want="Database\Base\location of site - remote"*

The file i'm searching in is structured as follows (all columns are tab seperated):

```
Database\Base\location of site             data1    data2    data3   
Database\Base\location of site - remote    data1    data2    data3  
Other_variable\something                   data1    data2    data3
```

My goal would be to only match the **first** line in this case.
Things i've tried so far:

`awk -v pattern="$variable_i_want" -F\\t '$1~pattern {print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt`
returns
`awk: warning: escape sequence '\B' treated as plain 'B'`

`grep -F "$variable_i_want" file.txt`
returns lines containing both matches (*location of site*  and *location of site - remote*). Leaving out the -F returns nothing because it interprets the backslashes and spaces as code instead of string (i guess)

I think a possible solution would be to match the variable in combination with a regex, something like `^$variable_i_want$` but I can't get this to work in either sed/awk or grep.

So, for clarity: i **only** want the line containing **$variable_i_want** to match.

Comment: What is in the `file.txt`?

Comment: The warning returned by awk tells me that your MVC is not actually tested. You have a `\B` in your real awk oneliner, please have a look and edit your example to reflect it. (you probably don't need the `\B` at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bash 4.4 or up, you can do

```
grep "^${variable_i_want@Q}$"$'\t' file.txt
```

The `^` matches the begining of the line, the `$'\t'` matches a tab character (note, this has to be outside of the original quotes...).  the `${...@Q}` escapes the backslashes and spaces in a manner that grep accepts.    If you have an older version of bash, you can use the `printf %q` instead:

```
grep "^$(printf %q "$variable_i_want")"$'\t' file.txt
```

or

```
grep "^$(printf "%q\t" "$variable_i_want")" file.txt
```

(since you're using printf anyways, you can have it output a literal tab character...)

example:

```
tmp> more file.txt
blah
Database\Base\location of site  data1   data2   data3
Database\Base\location of site - remote data1   data2   data3

tmp> printf "%q\n" "$variable_i_want"
Database\\Base\\location\ of\ site

tmp> grep "^$(printf "%q" "$variable_i_want")"$'\t' file.txt
Database\Base\location of site  data1   data2   data3
```

Answer (score 2):

After chatting with OP got to know his/her O.S is Ubnutu, so written and tested this code with Ubuntu 16.04.6

```
variable_dont_want='Database\\Base\\location of site - remote'
variable_i_want='Database\\Base\\location of site'
```

Now run following code:

```
awk -v var="$variable_i_want" -v var1="$variable_dont_want" 'index($0,var) && !index($0,var1)' Input_file
```

Output of above code was as follows.

```
Database\Base\location of site             data1    data2    data3
```

So we need to do 2 things here to make this work with `awk`:

- Have bash variables single quoted wrapped, rather than `"` to take `\` as a literal character, we need to tell variable that we need 2 of `\` in it.
- Now why we need to make variable understand that read `\` as `\\` because of `awk` it  should be escaped so that `awk` will NOT give warning messages etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help Ravinder, this workound seems to work on my system as well now. I prefer HardcoreHenry's solution though, because for your solution you need to **know** beforehand which variables you do not want, **and** you need to include this in your code; while Henry's solution automatically excludes everything that you don't want. Thanks a lot for the effort though!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to escape `\B` and use the `$` to enforce it to be at the end of the hook.

```
awk -F\\t '$1~/Database\\Base\\location of site$/ {print $1,$2,$3}' file.txt
```

Comment: This will work, but the variable name is not set on ```location of site```, it changes for every iteration the script runs through

Comment: if you need to use the -v, you'll have to add the escapes before you send the string to awk. You might find a smaller hook without "/" to enforce a workaround